# Replace characters only in headings

Tags: regex, markdown, sublimetext3

I have several files (see the Input section), what I need it to strip `[[` `]]` with REGEX, but the problem is that only for:

```
- # headings
- >quotes
```

All other brackets should be preserved. I cannot make it thru... I'm using the sublime reader.
If anybody have some ideas I will really appreciate it!
Thanks

#### Input

---

```
## [[zoom]] _[v]_

>[[move]] | [[very]] | [[quickly]]

__Synonyms__: [[buzz]] | [[dart]] | [[dash]] | [[dive]] | [[flash]] | [[fly]] | [[hum]] | [[hurtle]] | outstrip | [[rip]] | [[rocket]] | [[rush]] | [[shoot]] | [[shoot]] up | [[skyrocket]] | [[speed]] | [[streak]] | [[surge]] | [[tear]] | [[whirl]] | [[whiz]] | [[zip]]

__Concepts__: [[ACTIONS - MOTION#move oneself quickly (150)\|move oneself quickly]] 

__Antonyms__: decelerate, [[slow]]

## [[zip]] _[n]_

>[[enthusiasm]], [[energy]]

__Synonyms__: brio | [[drive]] | [[get]]-upand-[[go]] | [[go]] | [[gusto]] | [[life]] | liveliness | [[oomph]] | [[pep]] | [[pizzazz]] | [[punch]] | [[sparkle]] | [[spirit]] | [[verve]] | [[vigor]] | vim | [[vitality]] | [[zest]] | [[zing]]

__Concepts__: [[LIFE FORMS - GENERAL CHARACTERISTICS#personality (411)\|personality]], [[STATES - ABSTRACT#behavior (633)\|behavior]] 

__Antonyms__: [[apathy]], enervation, [[idleness]], [[laziness]], [[lethargy]]
 
## [[zip]] _[v]_

>[[move]] | [[about]] | [[quickly]]

__Synonyms__: [[bustle]] | [[dash]] | [[flash]] | [[fly]] | [[hasten]] | [[hurry]] | [[run]] | [[rush]] | [[shoot]] | [[speed]] | [[tear]] | waltz | [[whisk]] | [[whiz]] | [[zoom]]

__Concepts__: [[ACTIONS - MOTION#move oneself quickly (150)\|move oneself quickly]] 

__Antonyms__: decelerate, [[slow]]
```

---

#### Output

---

```
## zoom _[v]_

>move very quickly

__Synonyms__: [[buzz]] | [[dart]] | [[dash]] | [[dive]] | [[flash]] | [[fly]] | [[hum]] | [[hurtle]] | outstrip | [[rip]] | [[rocket]] | [[rush]] | [[shoot]] | [[shoot]] up | [[skyrocket]] | [[speed]] | [[streak]] | [[surge]] | [[tear]] | [[whirl]] | [[whiz]] | [[zip]]

__Concepts__: [[ACTIONS - MOTION#move oneself quickly (150)\|move oneself quickly]] 

__Antonyms__: decelerate, [[slow]]

## zip _[n]_

>enthusiasm, energy

__Synonyms__: brio | [[drive]] | [[get]]-upand-[[go]] | [[go]] | [[gusto]] | [[life]] | liveliness | [[oomph]] | [[pep]] | [[pizzazz]] | [[punch]] | [[sparkle]] | [[spirit]] | [[verve]] | [[vigor]] | vim | [[vitality]] | [[zest]] | [[zing]]

__Concepts__: [[LIFE FORMS - GENERAL CHARACTERISTICS#personality (411)\|personality]], [[STATES - ABSTRACT#behavior (633)\|behavior]] 

__Antonyms__: [[apathy]], enervation, [[idleness]], [[laziness]], [[lethargy]]
 
## zip _[v]_

>move about quickly

__Synonyms__: [[bustle]] | [[dash]] | [[flash]] | [[fly]] | [[hasten]] | [[hurry]] | [[run]] | [[rush]] | [[shoot]] | [[speed]] | [[tear]] | waltz | [[whisk]] | [[whiz]] | [[zoom]]

__Concepts__: [[ACTIONS - MOTION#move oneself quickly (150)\|move oneself quickly]] 

__Antonyms__: decelerate, [[slow]]
```

Comment: Can you show any rx that you already tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In sublime text editor you can use PCRE flavor of regex. Following should work for you.

Search regex:

```sh
(?:^[#>]|(?!^)\G).*?\K(?:\[\[|]])
```

Replace with an empty string.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GCJJzN/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `^[#>]`: Match `#` or `>` at the start
  - `|`: OR
  - `(?!^)\G`: Restart matching from end of the previous match
- `)`: End non-capture group
- `.*?`: Match 0 or more of any character (lazy)
- `\K`: Reset match info
- `(?:\[\[|]])`: Match `[[` or `]]`

Comment: Ok this is mind blowing! I was hoping really hoping there is some nifty regex solution, but this exceed my expectations!

Please do you have some good resource where I can dig deeper in PCRE regex?

Thank you very, very much! for this

Comment: You're welcome. [This is one of the best resource on PCRE](https://www.regular-expressions.info/pcre.html)

Comment: But when I test the ```RegEx Demo``` you wrote before, I got error ```engine error``` for some reason.

Comment: Here is the demo link: https://regex101.com/r/GCJJzN/1 and it is working fine there

Comment: Alternative solution is `^(?![#>]).*(*SKIP)(*F)|\[\[|]]`

Answer (score 3):

The following seems to work:

```
^_.*(*SKIP)(*F)|\[\[|]]
```

- `^` - Start string anchor.
- `_.*` - Match an underscore and 0+ other character than newline.
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` - Backtracking control verbs to where `(*F)` is shorthand for `(*FAIL)`. This combination of controls basically says: [*"Throw away anything you can match to the left of me."*](https://www.rexegg.com/backtracking-control-verbs.html#skipfail)
- `|` - Or:
- `\[\[` - A double literal open bracket.
- `|` - Or:
- `]]` - A double literal closing bracket.

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/XlpvjJ/1)

---

To make this more restrictive you can use:

```
^[^#>\n].*(*SKIP)(*F)|\[\[|]]
```

Where the only diference is that the negated character class makes sure we not just looking for lines starting with an underscore.

---

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: This is very good but can we assume that we have to ignore only underscore lines? That's why I suggested a variant of this

Comment: @anubhava, yeah, it's why I included a variant at the end of the answer to be more explicit of what we **don't** want to match though the sample data suggests that the underscore may just work =).

Comment: Wau! So this is pure regex solution! No perl syntax, right?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a much easier way to do this. You just need to check if the line startswith the `##` or `>` string.

The below code is python.

Here's how I did it:

```
for line in my_file_data.split('\n'):
    if line.startswith(('##','>')):
        line = line.replace('[[','').replace(']]','')
    print (line)
```

I stored all the raw data into `my_file_data`. Then did a split to get each line.

The output of this is:

```
## zoom _[v]_

>move | very | quickly

__Synonyms__: [[buzz]] | [[dart]] | [[dash]] | [[dive]] | [[flash]] | [[fly]] | [[hum]] | [[hurtle]] | outstrip | [[rip]] | [[rocket]] | [[rush]] | [[shoot]] | [[shoot]] up | [[skyrocket]] | [[speed]] | [[streak]] | [[surge]] | [[tear]] | [[whirl]] | [[whiz]] | [[zip]]

__Concepts__: [[ACTIONS - MOTION#move oneself quickly (150)\|move oneself quickly]] 

__Antonyms__: decelerate, [[slow]]

## zip _[n]_

>enthusiasm, energy

__Synonyms__: brio | [[drive]] | [[get]]-upand-[[go]] | [[go]] | [[gusto]] | [[life]] | liveliness | [[oomph]] | [[pep]] | [[pizzazz]] | [[punch]] | [[sparkle]] | [[spirit]] | [[verve]] | [[vigor]] | vim | [[vitality]] | [[zest]] | [[zing]]

__Concepts__: [[LIFE FORMS - GENERAL CHARACTERISTICS#personality (411)\|personality]], [[STATES - ABSTRACT#behavior (633)\|behavior]] 

__Antonyms__: [[apathy]], enervation, [[idleness]], [[laziness]], [[lethargy]]
 
## zip _[v]_

>move | about | quickly

__Synonyms__: [[bustle]] | [[dash]] | [[flash]] | [[fly]] | [[hasten]] | [[hurry]] | [[run]] | [[rush]] | [[shoot]] | [[speed]] | [[tear]] | waltz | [[whisk]] | [[whiz]] | [[zoom]]

__Concepts__: [[ACTIONS - MOTION#move oneself quickly (150)\|move oneself quickly]] 

__Antonyms__: decelerate, [[slow]]
```

Comment: Yes this is working also.

| I loop all files >>> Call your procedure >>> Read back changes into file |

Thank you for the python solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can split the text into lines, and map through each line to do the cleanup conditionally:

```js
function cleanBrackets(text) {
  return text
  .split(/\r?\n/)   // split into lines
  .map((line) => {  // for each line:
    if(line.match(/^[#>]/)) { // if heading or quote:
      line = line.replace(/\[\[([^\]]+)\]\]/g, '$1'); // cleanup
    }
    return line;
  })
  .join('\n');
}

console.log(cleanBrackets(`## [[zoom]] _[v]_

>[[move]] | [[very]] | [[quickly]]

__Synonyms__: [[buzz]] | [[dart]] | [[dash]] | [[dive]] | [[flash]] | [[fly]] | [[hum]] | [[hurtle]] | outstrip | [[rip]] | [[rocket]] | [[rush]] | [[shoot]] | [[shoot]] up | [[skyrocket]] | [[speed]] | [[streak]] | [[surge]] | [[tear]] | [[whirl]] | [[whiz]] | [[zip]]

__Concepts__: [[ACTIONS - MOTION#move oneself quickly (150)\|move oneself quickly]] 

__Antonyms__: decelerate, [[slow]]

## [[zip]] _[n]_

>[[enthusiasm]], [[energy]]

__Synonyms__: brio | [[drive]] | [[get]]-upand-[[go]] | [[go]] | [[gusto]] | [[life]] | liveliness | [[oomph]] | [[pep]] | [[pizzazz]] | [[punch]] | [[sparkle]] | [[spirit]] | [[verve]] | [[vigor]] | vim | [[vitality]] | [[zest]] | [[zing]]

__Concepts__: [[LIFE FORMS - GENERAL CHARACTERISTICS#personality (411)\|personality]], [[STATES - ABSTRACT#behavior (633)\|behavior]] 

__Antonyms__: [[apathy]], enervation, [[idleness]], [[laziness]], [[lethargy]]
 
## [[zip]] _[v]_

>[[move]] | [[about]] | [[quickly]]

__Synonyms__: [[bustle]] | [[dash]] | [[flash]] | [[fly]] | [[hasten]] | [[hurry]] | [[run]] | [[rush]] | [[shoot]] | [[speed]] | [[tear]] | waltz | [[whisk]] | [[whiz]] | [[zoom]]

__Concepts__: [[ACTIONS - MOTION#move oneself quickly (150)\|move oneself quickly]] 

__Antonyms__: decelerate, [[slow]]`));
```

Result:

```
## zoom _[v]_

>move | very | quickly

__Synonyms__: [[buzz]] | [[dart]] | [[dash]] | [[dive]] | [[flash]] | [[fly]] | [[hum]] | [[hurtle]] | outstrip | [[rip]] | [[rocket]] | [[rush]] | [[shoot]] | [[shoot]] up | [[skyrocket]] | [[speed]] | [[streak]] | [[surge]] | [[tear]] | [[whirl]] | [[whiz]] | [[zip]]

__Concepts__: [[ACTIONS - MOTION#move oneself quickly (150)|move oneself quickly]] 

__Antonyms__: decelerate, [[slow]]

## zip _[n]_

>enthusiasm, energy

__Synonyms__: brio | [[drive]] | [[get]]-upand-[[go]] | [[go]] | [[gusto]] | [[life]] | liveliness | [[oomph]] | [[pep]] | [[pizzazz]] | [[punch]] | [[sparkle]] | [[spirit]] | [[verve]] | [[vigor]] | vim | [[vitality]] | [[zest]] | [[zing]]

__Concepts__: [[LIFE FORMS - GENERAL CHARACTERISTICS#personality (411)|personality]], [[STATES - ABSTRACT#behavior (633)|behavior]] 

__Antonyms__: [[apathy]], enervation, [[idleness]], [[laziness]], [[lethargy]]
 
## zip _[v]_

>move | about | quickly

__Synonyms__: [[bustle]] | [[dash]] | [[flash]] | [[fly]] | [[hasten]] | [[hurry]] | [[run]] | [[rush]] | [[shoot]] | [[speed]] | [[tear]] | waltz | [[whisk]] | [[whiz]] | [[zoom]]

__Concepts__: [[ACTIONS - MOTION#move oneself quickly (150)|move oneself quickly]] 

__Antonyms__: decelerate, [[slow]]
```

Comment: The problem is that I have 13.000 of such a files! I was looking for more non-code pure regex solution. That I can just run in sublime reader in batch for all files.

What is the programming language you are using? It is a javascript?

Comment: Yes this is JavaScript and can easily be mapped to any language. But I see you are looking for a programmer's editor search & replace

Comment: Not sure it is possible with a single regex because you need a regex within a regex. Possibly use a one-liner perl? What OS?

Comment: I' m using Mac OS